# Format for mp4 and jpg data stored in S3 (through Node backend) and retrieved with Swift (through Node endpoint)

Tags: ios, node.js, swift, amazon-s3

Currently storing image jpg on S3 and retrieving its base64 encoding. Was wondering if this was "best practice" (in terms of performance and storage size) for a Swift iOS app?

Also storing mp4 files and was wondering if I should encode these in any way for retrieval, stream these back (preferably not), or some other way of sending these? (pros + cons of each method).

Thank you!